# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli

For 2 days now I'm trying to solve this, but unfortunately no result. Let me tell you my story about the problem. I've bulid an application on a site, and the application deals with the reviews. But, I'm trying to put it on another site, and I copyed the php files, the sql file from the old site, and moved them to the new site (they are on different FTP servers). When I'm trying to go to the pages from the application, I receive this FATAL ERROR:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

The code that I wrote to connect to the database is this (with hidden credentials):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("","*the_name*","*the_pass*","*the_database*");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Why do I get the error? It works on the old server, and the code I think it's not the problem, because it works on localhost, and on the new server it doesn't. Can anyone help me?

Comment: looks line in you server mysqli extension is not enabled. check if mysqli is enabled `phpinfo()`

Comment: please enable mysqli extension

Comment: I followed below link for my problem :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/773601/php-mysqli-extension-in-ubuntu-16-04-not-working-after-upgrade-to-version-7-0-6

Comment: if you come from php storm -> https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error- or https://web.archive.org/web/20200805054537/https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error-

Answer (score 72):

Simply do it

`sudo apt install php-mysqli`

It works perfectly and it is version independent

Comment: it works thanks in my case I had to run sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
then restart apache sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: @ScottyBlades try merely `sudo apt`. I edited accordingly

Answer (score 53):

On Windows, the extension ***extension=php_mysqli.dll*** can be enabled by removing the semicolon ';' at the beginning of the extension name from the php.ini file.

Also, use `phpinfo()` to verify, which actual `php.ini` file you need to edit. On the fresh install, you need to rename one of the provided php.ini-templates into actual `php.ini` that PHP could use.

Comment: Also, always check your PHP and Apache error logs. I used "#" instead of ";" to mark a comment in php.ini and got strange errors (including "Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()") from web pages.

Comment: Or `extension=mysqli`.

Answer (score 25):

For [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), do:

```
sudo yum install php-mysqli
```

Comment: No package php-mysqli available. CentOS release 6.9 (Final). What should I do?

Comment: yes, I also got same message "No package php-mysqli available", what to do ?

Comment: I recommend using the IUS repo for php 5.6 on Centos 7.  Read the documentation at https://ius.io

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu I had to install `php5 mysql` extension:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: In addition, check that extension "extension=mysqli.so" is enabled (uncommented) in the "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" file if you're on Ubuntu/Debian. Then restart the server "service apache2 restart".

Comment: This do not work on Ubuntue
`E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate`

Comment: You have to install phpX-mysql where X depends. In my case I ran "php -v" and saw my PHP version was 7.4 and did "sudo apt install php7.4-mysql". You can also do "sudo apt-cache search php | grep mysql" to see which versions are available.

Answer (score 9):

Happens when php extensions are not being used by default. In your php.ini file, change
 `;extension=php_mysql.dll` 
to 
`extension=php_mysql.dll`. 
**If this error logs, then add path to this dll file, eg
 `extension=C:\Php\php-???-nts-Win32-VC11-x86\ext\php_mysql.dll`
Do same for `php_mysqli.dll` and `php_pdo_mysql.dll`. Save and run your code again.

Comment: Also restart Apache.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the module installed and set your PHP.INI file properly, check your apache error log for something like the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\ext\\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

In this case, your extension directory is not what you think it is.  You may neeed to set it explicitly, like so:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

Comment: That was my case, thank you. PS: As documented in php.ini, it's sufficient to add `extension_dir = "ext"` on Windows and `extension_dir = "./"` on the other systems.

Answer (score 5):

Mine was a bit different for php7 on centos7.

In /etc/php.ini

;   extension=mysqli

to

extension=mysqli

Comment: Similar [change](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PHP) for archlinux, uncomment in /etc/php/php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

On Raspberry Pi I had to install php5 mysql extension.

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

After installing the client, the webserver should be restarted. In case you're using apache, the following should work:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Restarting apache worked for ubuntu regular non-raspi for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you host the server yourself, and that server happens to be Apache, you can also get this error even if you have uncommented `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in php.ini.

You also need to tell Apache where to find php.ini by using the `PHPIniDir` directive in Apache's httpd.conf

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "<path-to-folder-where-php-ini-lives>"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use ubuntu 16.04 (maybe and above),you have this module already but not enabled by default. Just do this:

```
sudo phpenmod mysqli
```

Comment: Well this got me some new info... but it seems it is not installed by default on WSL Ubuntu 18.... 'WARNING: Module mysqli ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available'

Comment: you can install it if missing by `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in the, but the mysqli PHP extension is not installed on your machine. Please contact your service provider to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli isn't installed on the new server. Run phpinfo() to confirm.

```
<?php 

phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be the issue for you, but I was struggling with this error. I discovered what was causing my problem, though I can't really explain as to why.

For me, mysqli_connect was working fine where the connection was made on pages in any various sub-directory. For some reason though, the same code referenced on pages in the root directory was returning this error. The strange thing is that it was working fine on my localhost environment in MAMP in the root directory, however on my shared host it was not.

After struggling to figure out what was giving me "Error 500" white screen from this "PHP Fatal Error," I went through the code and stumbled upon this code in the error handling that was suggested by the PHP Manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

I randomly decided to remove it and, voila, connection to the database working in root directories. Maybe someone smarter than me can explain this, for anyone struggling with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I followed below link to fix this problem. Make sure to enable following Module.

 php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli

Link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/773601/php-mysqli-extension-in-ubuntu-16-04-not-working-after-upgrade-to-version-7-0-6

Answer (score 0):

In my windows 11 I am using XAMPP 8.2.4

In my case the `php.ini` is located inside `<drive-latter>:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp` folder

And the extension was looked like this `;extension=mysqli`

Just remove the `;` and restart the server.

**Addition:**

When I was using `php artisan serve` in terminal for **Laravel** project, it was using `<drive-latter>:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\php.ini` file.

And when I was using `localhost/project_name/public` from address bar, it was using `<drive-latter>:\xampp\php\php.ini` file.

You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you get here trying to setup a GitHub Codespaces with Docker and devcontainer.json, update the Dockerfile to the following, with the last 'RUN' line being the key line.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:0-8.2

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install MySQL extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```