# Undefined function mysqli_connect() when try to connect to mysql database why?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'viadonau');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'vinoservice');
echo DB_SERVER ;
echo DB_USERNAME;
echo DB_PASSWORD;
echo DB_DATABASE;
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

I alway get a fatal error and i dont know why....on mysql workbench i can connect to the database...and in PHPStorm i can also configure the data source and i can run  a query but in php i cant connect. Thanks for help!!!

Comment: keep password as empty if you are working in local..

Comment: the error seems to say that the mysqli extension is not installed/activated see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect?rq=1

Comment: looks to me the MySQLi php library is not enabled.. check it with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: I add these two lines but not working yet :S :
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=C:\Utils\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll

Comment: You just have to remove ; from php.ini `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and ofcource restart apache

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new PHP file and add the following to it, it should show if MySQLi is enabled or not.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you don't have MySQLi then it will show up with [no mysqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUNXl.png)

If you do have it, it will show [mysqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M5B1.png)

You can install the MySQLi extension through terminal by using the following, if on PHP5

```
apt-get install php5-mysqli
```

However if you use php 7 use

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysqli
```