# Call to undefined function mysqli_query() error

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysqli_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\asd.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\asd.php on line 2

when simply running any mysqli cmd in any php file e.g :

```
<?php  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','my_user','my_password','my_db'); ?>
```

I have already enabled the extension in my php.ini file and I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I just can't.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must not have enabled the extension correctly.

Comment: Did you restart apache after enabling it?

Comment: well i enabled uncommented "extension=mysqli" and have and yes i have restarted  apache thanks for the help, i have been trying to fix this for hours with no success

Comment: Make sure you updated the correct php.ini. There are separate init files for CLI and web.

Comment: are they both in the same php directory ? if not i have edited the only on in  my php dir

Comment: im sorry, im new to php and mysql , i don't know where those seperate files are contained

Comment: [How to find location of php.ini](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/)

Comment: then yes I have the right php.ini

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect) the line in php.ini should be `extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Comment: but see that is the problem, my file doesn't  contain `extension=php_mysqli.dll` so i tried adding it and resetting apache and it still does not work.There is actually no .dll in my php.ini

Comment: Maybe you don't have the extension in the first place and need to download it.

Comment: when i run this cmd it shows that i have sql right ?`C:\php>php.exe -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]`

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Does the extension show up in `phpinfo()` on the web?

Comment: the question you have referenced does not solve my problem by the way, i don't know why this is so complicated and yes it does show up

Comment: @sinsy Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of the "mysqli" section of the page generated by `phpinfo();`.

Answer (score -3):

Can you try this code below:

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

And let me if it works thanks.

Comment: this is what I get when I execute it `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\asd.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\asd.php on line 2`

Comment: it seems as if php doesn't even recognize what mysqli_connect() is and stops execution right there , but I have all the prerequisites needed.

Comment: What's the point of this answer? If the function doesn't exist, how can it set the error code?

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: I think the best way is to speak to your hosting provider and tell them what the issue is, by the way I don’t know why did I get minus 3, the code I provide it earlier was just in case that @sinsy was not typed in correctly, please fix thanks