# Mysqli_Connect is an undefined function

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to populate my server with my database but I keep running into this error:
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I've looked online and I've edited my php.ini file to include the extension=mysqli as shown in the attached screenshot
[image]

I'm perfectly able to connect to my DB in netbeans and I'm kind of stumped on why this function is stilled undefined.

If anyone has any other approaches I could take that would be super appreciative :)

Thank you

Comment: Did you restart the server after making INI changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Things that you should check for debugging.

- If you change your `php.ini` while the server is running, restart your server because whenever you make changes to your `php.ini` you must restart it for it to be effective.
- Make sure that `mysqli.dll` or `php_mysqli.dll` for windows or php `mysqli.so` binary for linux or mac os, is existing in the `ext` folder on your php installation folder as you enabled it on your `php.ini`.
- In the past I have multiple PHP version installed on my machine, if you have the same scenario, make sure that your server (example: Apache, Nginx) is pointing the correct PHP version you want to use where you also configured your `php.ini`.