# Codeigniter mysqli Issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am getting this error as below
Can anyone help?
PHP Version: 7.4
MySql Version: 5.7.31-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL)
mysqli package tik is ok

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in ..domain/admin/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:77 Stack trace: #0 ..domain/admin/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php(92): CI_DB_mysqli_driver->db_connect() #1 ..domain/admin/system/database/DB_driver.php(116): CI_DB_mysqli_driver->db_pconnect() #2 ..domain/admin/system/database/DB.php(149): CI_DB_driver->initialize() #3 ..domain/admin/system/core/Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL) #4 ..domain/admin/system/core/Loader.php(1172): CI_Loader->database() #5 ..domain/admin/system/core/Loader.php(153): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #6 ..domain/admin/system/core/Controller.php(52): CI_Loader->initialize() #7 ..domain/admin/application/controllers/ in ..domain/admin/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 77

Comment: Have you installed and enabled the mysqli PHP extension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect

Comment: I am using cPanel and it looks installed

Comment: Looking at the error message, I would disagree. Create a PHP file with just `<?php phpinfo();` in it and browse to that file. Check if you find mysqli on that page.